# Change Columns Name dynamically in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, multiple-columns

I have a query result like this :

```
Date       User1 User2 User3 ....
----------------------------------
1/1/2000   55     78    98   ...
1/1/2001   26     33    56   ...
1/1/2002   88     67    12   ...
```

The number of columns is not known because it is the result of a pivot query.

I would like to change the name the columns to something that looks like this :

```
Date    User1 (blue)  User2 (green)  User3(brown)
```

The color is an information I retrieve from another table.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Edit : Here is the query.

```
  DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(C.Name)  
                    from [History]



            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT [Date],' + @cols +' 
             from 
             (
                select [Date], Name, Value
                from [History]


             ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for Name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Then show your query which gives you this result.

Comment: Where does these values `blue`, `green`, `brown` come from? Do you want to write them manually for each user name? If so then list the columns' names manually not dynamically since, you will write the colors' names manually after all.

Comment: ***The number of columns is not known because it is the result of a pivot query.*** Please show us the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93dbc/8)

**Schema Setup**:

```
create table history (date datetime, name varchar(10), value int);
insert history values
 ('20130101', 'user1', 123),
 ('20130101', 'user2', 124),
 ('20130101', 'user3', 125),
 ('20130102', 'user1', 223),
 ('20130102', 'user3', 223),
 ('20130103', 'user2', 323);

create table colours (name varchar(10), colour_name varchar(10));
insert colours values
 ('user1', 'blue'),
 ('user2', 'green'),
 ('user3', 'brown');
```

**Query**:

```
DECLARE @scols nvarchar(max),
        @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((
  SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(C.Name)  
  from (select distinct name from [History]) C
  ORDER BY C.Name
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');

select @scols = STUFF((
  SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(colour_Name)  
  from (select distinct c.name, x.colour_name
        from [History] C
        JOIN colours x on x.name = c.name) y
  ORDER BY Name
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');

set @query = '
    SELECT [Date],' + @scols +' 
    from (
        select [Date], Name, Value
        from [History]
         ) x
    pivot 
         (
        max(value)
        for Name in (' + @cols + ')
         ) p ';

-- print @query --<< uncomment this line to see the query that gets generated
exec (@query);
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93dbc/8/0)**:

```
|                           DATE |   BLUE |  GREEN |  BROWN |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    123 |    124 |    125 |
| January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    223 | (null) |    223 |
| January, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 | (null) |    323 | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the mapping You can use a lookup table of old column name to new column name for example

```
CREATE TABLE colname(
  oldname varchar(20),
  newname varchar(20)
)

insert into colname values ( 'user1','user1 (blue)');
insert into colname values ( 'user2','user2 (green)');
```

then you can build an sql statement that uses this mapping

```
declare @sq varchar(2000)
set @sq ='select date'
select @sq = @sq +  ',' + oldname + ' as [' + newname +']' from colname
set @sq = @sq + 'from ( existing query goes here ) ' 
select @sq
```

when the sql in @sq looks good you can replace the last select with

```
exec ( @sq )
```

to run the query

Answer (score -2):

```
select Date, User1 as blue,User2 as green,User3 as brown from tableName
```

Use query like this.

Make use of '`as`' keyword for changing column name.

Comment: Those are static column names. OP specifically asked for dynamic col names, not just how to rename them