# dynamic column name in sql server 2008 in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I use the following syntax in stored procedure,

```
set @count = (select count(*) from [dbo].[employee] where @column_name ='T')
```

Comment: No, you can't, you need to use dynamic sql. One example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185425/change-columns-name-dynamically-in-sql

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_Name
@Column_Name NVARCHAR(128),
@COUNT INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'SELECT @count = count(*) from [dbo].[employee] where ' + QUOTENAME(@Column_Name) 
             + N' =''T'''

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                      ,N'@COUNT INT OUTPUT'
                      ,@COUNT OUTPUT

END
```