# create a view which include exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to create the view of the following statement:

```
declare @tab1 varchar(20);

declare @tab2 varchar(20);

declare @tab3 varchar(20);

select @tab1 = tablet from result where RANK = 1;

select @tab2 = tablet from result where RANK = 2;

select @tab3 = tablet from result where RANK = 3;


exec('
SELECT [1] AS '+@tab1+', [2] AS '+@tab2+', [3] AS '+@tab3+'
FROM (SELECT RANK, time, row_number() OVER (partition BY koy
ORDER BY time ASC) AS ranking
FROM result) s 
PIVOT (max(time) FOR rank IN ([1], [2], [3])) p');
```

Comment: And whats seems to be the problem ? You don't honestly expect us to guess..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Columns Name dynamically in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185425/change-columns-name-dynamically-in-sql)

Comment: Please google and learn about the CREATE VIEW statement, and its restrictions.

Comment: Please provide a small dataset for testing

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a view with dynamic column names, it's definition must be static.

Unfortunately what you want to do is not even possible (allowed) in a table-valued multistatement function, since these do not allow dynamic SQL execution as well.